# Viewmodel preserving data after finishing activity

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a MainActivity form that I am opening CreatePassword Activity in that, I am saving password and finish CreatePasswordActivity with sending Intent back to MainActivity.

Like **MainActivity -----> CreatePassword(Finish) ---Intent----> MainActivity**

```
  private fun observeIntentResult() {
        generatePasswordViewModel.getIntentResult().observe(this@CreatePasswordActivity, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { intent ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Got Same Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
        })
    }
```

But Now when I open CreatePasswordActivity again from MainActivity, it's LiveData automatically sending previous data (intent) and CreatePasswordActivity is suddenly finished.

Do I have any mistake in implementing code? Anybody have idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you are calling this function in onCreate() :/

Comment: Yes, I am calling from onCreate(), so where should I need to call? I have no idea more than this

Comment: Wrap it with a condition to make sure that it's the first time to be called , You can for example ,put a variable in the intent you open createPassword with from MainActivity , then Override onActivityResult and set its value from there to a member value in PasswordActivity and check its value in the Condition if it equals specific value then it's called from the intent so don't call this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used below class, which helped me to resolve current issue, will see and update answer in future if I will be able to find any better solution.

```
open class VolatileLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    private val lastValueSeq = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val wrappers = HashMap<Observer<in T>, Observer<T>>()

    @MainThread
    public override fun setValue(value: T) {
        lastValueSeq.incrementAndGet()
        super.setValue(value)
    }

    @MainThread
    public override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        val observerWrapper = ObserverWrapper(lastValueSeq, observer)
        wrappers[observer] = observerWrapper
        super.observe(owner, observerWrapper)
    }

    @MainThread
    public override fun observeForever(observer: Observer<in T>) {
        val observerWrapper = ObserverWrapper(lastValueSeq, observer)
        wrappers[observer] = observerWrapper
        super.observeForever(observerWrapper)
    }

    @MainThread
    public override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<in T>) {
        val observerWrapper = wrappers[observer]
        observerWrapper?.let {
            wrappers.remove(observerWrapper)
            super.removeObserver(observerWrapper)
        }
    }
}

private class ObserverWrapper<T>(private var currentSeq: AtomicInteger, private val observer: Observer<in T>) : Observer<T> {
    private val initialSeq = currentSeq.get()
    private var _observer: Observer<in T> = Observer {
        if (currentSeq.get() != initialSeq) {
            // Optimization: this wrapper implementation is only needed in the beginning.
            // Once a valid call is made (i.e. with a different concurrent sequence), we
            // get rid of it any apply the real implementation as a direct callthrough.
            _observer = observer
            _observer.onChanged(it)
        }
    }

    override fun onChanged(value: T) {
        _observer.onChanged(value)
    }
}
```